# Reverse the overlay css on hover

Tags: html, css

I want to reverse the overlay on hover. I couldn't figure this out. I would like the text to be shown at first and when you hover over the image the text, and the overlay should disappear. Thanks in advance. Here is the code:

```css
.img-box {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.overlay {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s ease;
    background-color: #3d3d3eb8;
    position: absolute;
}
.text {
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}
.img-box:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
    width:12%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="img-box">
        <div class="overlay">
       <div class="text">Title here</div>
      </div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/230/330"                              alt="title">
 </div>
  </div><!-- // image overlay //-->
</div>
```

Comment: codepen link 404s

Comment: https://codepen.io/NerdyGal/pen/GYMYXb

Comment: Hey Nerdy Girl. Your question will likely be downvoted and potentially closed because code-related questions require you to include your code *in the question itself*. To avoid this, please edit your question and instead put your code in a runnable Stack Snippet. (the button on top that looks like `<>`)

Comment: A note to the close-voters: Consider approving the edit instead.

Comment: Side note, your background color isn’t right. It should only be 6 characters not 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code example works fine but the thing you need to do is to swap the opacity values. Like this:

```
.overlay {
  opacity: 1; /* 1 instead of 0 */
}

.img-box:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 0; /* 0 instead of 1 */
}
```

I hope this could be to any help.

Comment: Thank you so much Lindebro!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean? You just need to exchange the initial values (opacity and width) with the hover values. Also available in [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BqwvKY).

```css
.img-box {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.overlay {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 12%;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: .5s ease;
    background-color: #3d3d3eb8;
    position: absolute;
}
.text {
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}
.img-box:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 0;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="img-box">
            <div class="overlay">
           <div class="text">Title here</div>
        </div>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/230/330"                              alt="title">
     </div>
    </div><!-- // image overlay //-->
</div>
```